# Yahoo Oath | Local character in callback address

Tags: yahoo-oauth

When I'm creating my application in **YDN** (https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/create/), I have an error with my callback address because of a local character (dyn.légen.de).

Error: **Callback Domain must be a valid URL.**

Is there an established solution for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I respond myself : 
I have to use the IDN (Internationalized domain name) version of my domain name !